# What is the system tray icon size for retina display?

Tags: macos, qt, retina-display, pyqt5

I've created a Qt5 app using PyQt5, now I am adapting images to be compatible with Retina Display on OS X. I've creating duplicates of them with the @2x modificator, but the fact is that I've not been able to make the tray icon to look correctly, I think it is because I am using the image in the wrong size.
Does anybody have any idea?

[image: Blurry icon]

Comment: I think this question and answer will answer your question too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714923/os-x-icons-size

Comment: Hi, I've tried the sizes mentioned there but it haven't worked, I still see the icon blurry... Any idea? Does anybody know if unlike the other images, Qt is rendering the tray icon in the wrong way?

Comment: You're not telling us what version of Qt you're using. Most likely, the version you're using doesn't have retina support implemented yet for the menubar ("tray") icon. I don't know offhand if the most recent release at the time - Qt 5.3 - has this fixed or not. You may want to check if a bug report exists for this, if not report a bug.

Comment: Hi, I am using 5.3.0-stable, sorry I couldn't find anything about that in the changelog. I don't know whether I did wrong or it has not been fixed

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works with Qt, but you can use a combined file with Xcode.

Within Terminal, you can combine both icons by executing this command:

```
tiffutil -cathidpicheck tray_icon.png tray_icon@2x.png -out tray_icon.tiff
```